# Why does the order affect the rounding when adding multiple doubles in C#

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, rounding, precision

Consider the following C# code:

```
double result1 = 1.0 + 1.1 + 1.2;
double result2 = 1.2 + 1.0 + 1.1;

if (result1 == result2)
{
    ...
}
```

result1 should always equal result2 right? The thing is, it doesn't. result1 is 3.3 and result2 is 3.3000000000000003. The only difference is the order of the constants.

I know that doubles are implemented in such a way that rounding issues can occur. I'm aware that I can use decimals instead if I need absolute precision. Or that I can use Math.Round() in my if statement. I'm just a nerd who wants to understand what the C# compiler is doing. Can anyone tell me?

**Edit:**

Thanks to everyone who's so far suggested reading up on floating point arithmetic and/or talked about the inherent inaccuracy of how the CPU handles doubles. But I feel the main thrust of my question is still unanswered. Which is my fault for not phrasing it correctly. Let me put it like this:

Breaking down the above code, I would expect the following operations to be happening:

```
double r1 = 1.1 + 1.2;
double r2 = 1.0 + r1
double r3 = 1.0 + 1.1
double r4 = 1.2 + r3
```

Let's assume that each of the above additions had a rounding error (numbered e1..e4). So r1 contains rounding error e1, r2 includes rounding errors e1 + e2, r3 contains e3 and r4 contains e3 + e4.

Now, I don't know how exactly how the rounding errors happen but I would have expected e1+e2 to equal e3+e4. Clearly it doesn't, but that seems somehow wrong to me. Another thing is that when I run the above code, I don't get any rounding errors. That's what makes me think it's the C# compiler that's doing something weird rather than the CPU.

I know I'm asking a lot and maybe the best answer anyone can give is to go and do a PHD in CPU design, but I just thought I'd ask.

**Edit 2**

Looking at the IL from my original code sample, it's clear that it's the compiler not the CPU that's doing this:

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
.entrypoint
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] float64 result1,
        [1] float64 result2)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldc.r8 3.3
    L_000a: stloc.0 
    L_000b: ldc.r8 3.3000000000000003
    L_0014: stloc.1 
    L_0015: ret 
}
```

The compiler is adding up the numbers for me!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I would have expected e1+e2 to equal e3+e4.

That's not entirely unlike expecting

```
 floor( 5/3 ) + floor( 2/3 + 1 )
```

to equal

```
 floor( 5/3 + 2/3 ) + floor( 1 )
```

except you're multiplying by 2^53 before taking the floor.

Using 12 bit precision floating point and truncation with your values:

```
1.0            =  1.00000000000
1.1            =  1.00011001100
1.2            =  1.00110011001

1.0 + 1.1      = 10.00011001100 // extended during sum
r1 = 1.0 + 1.1 = 10.0001100110  // truncated to 12 bit
r1  + 1.2      = 11.01001100101 // extended during sum
r2 = r1  + 1.2 = 11.0100110010  // truncated to 12 bit

1.1 + 1.2      = 10.01001100110 // extended during sum
r3 = 1.1 + 1.2 = 10.0100110011  // truncated to 12 bit
r3 + 1.0       = 11.01001100110 // extended during sum
r4 = r3  + 1.0 = 11.0100110011  // truncated to 12 bit
```

So changing the order of operations/truncations causes the the error to change, and r4 != r2. If you add 1.1 and 1.2 in this system, the last bit carries, so in not lost on truncation. If you add 1.0 to 1.1, the last bit of 1.1 is lost and so the result is not the same.

In one ordering, the rounding (by truncation) removes a trailing `1`.

In the other ordering, the rounding removes a trailing `0` both times.

One does not equal zero; so the errors are not the same.

Doubles have many more bits of precision, and C# probably uses rounding rather than truncation, but hopefully this simple model shows you different errors can happen with different orderings of the same values.

The difference between fp and maths is that + is shorthand for 'add then round' rather than just add.

Comment: The example is good, but you have changed the order of the operations compared to the original code. The OP did the same in the first edit.

Answer (score 6):

The c# compiler isn't doing anything. The CPU is.

if you have A in a CPU register, and you then add B, the result stored in that register is A+B, approximated to the floating precision used

If you then add C, the error adds up. This error addition is not a transitive operation, thus the final difference.

Comment: But if A+B produces a rounding error and A+C doesn't, wouldn't (A+C)+B still have the same rounding error as A+B? I get that rounding errors add up, I'm asking why is the order important.

Comment: no, A+B produces an error e1, and then A+B +C produces another error e2, so the final error is e1+e2. If A+C provides no error, A+C +B provides a single error e3, which has no reason to match e1+e2. You should google for floating point arithmetic for more info.

Comment: I guess I'm not making myself clear, let me rephrase "if A+B makes e1, (A+B)+C makes e2, A+C makes e3 and (A+C)+B makes e4, why does e1+e2 not equal e3+e4? So far, you've told me that it doesn't but not why it doesn't."

Comment: e3 and e4 may be zero, where e1 and e2 aren't.

Comment: @dant : try to compute 1/3*3 : the result is 1 because of the obvious simplification. now try to compute 2/3 (result is 0.6666...), add 0.3333,the result is now 0.999999...instead of 1). The same kind of reasoning goes for floating point arithmetic. It's well explained on wikipedia (see link below)

Comment: I've always assumed that you can't compare two floating point numbers for equality. Whenever I find such a thing in code, unless it's comparing to 0, I get chills.

Answer (score 4):

See [the classic paper (What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic)](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) on the subject. This kind of stuff is what happens with floating point arithmetic. It takes a computer scientist to tell you that 1/3+1/3+1/3 **is'nt** equal to 1...

Comment: I admit that floating point arithmetic scares me.  As a rule of thumb, I refuse to use it unless I must.

Comment: Use them when useful: where approximations are OK. Physical simulation, externally acquired measurements, graphic layout (for varying levels of permissible approximation). Money -- not so much! There is no tool so simple you can't possibly hurt yourself with it... (hm, fatal tweezer accidents?).

Answer (score 2):

Order of floating point operations is important. Doesn't directly answer your question, but you should always be careful comparing floating point numbers. It's usual to include a tolerance:

```
double epsilon = 0.0000001;
if (abs(result1 - result2) <= epsilon)
{
    ...
}
```

This may be of interest: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1):

> result1 should always equal result2
>   right?

**Wrong**. That's true in mathematics, but no in [floating-point arithmetics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

You'll need to read some [Numerical Analysis primer](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 1):

Why the errors aren't the same depending on order can be explained with a different example.

Let's say that for numbers below 10, it can store all the numbers, so it can store 1, 2, 3, and so on up to and including 10, but after 10, it can only store every second number, due to internal loss of precision, in other words, it can only store 10, 12, 14, etc.

Now, with that example, you'll see why the following produces different results:

```
1 + 1 + 1 + 10 = 12 (or 14, depending on rounding)
10 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 10
```

The problem with floating point numbers is that they can't be represented accurately, and the error doesn't always go the same way, so the order will matter.

For instance, 3.00000000003 + 3.00000000003 might end up being 6.00000000005 (notice not 6 at the end), but 3.00000000003 + 2.99999999997 might end up being 6.00000000001, and with that:

```
step 1: 3.00000000003 + 3.00000000003 = 6.00000000005
step 2: 6.00000000005 + 2.99999999997 = 9.00000000002
```

but, change the order:

```
step 1: 3.00000000003 + 2.99999999997 = 6.00000000001
step 2: 6.00000000001 + 3.00000000003 = 9.00000000004
```

So it will matter.

Now, of course, you might be lucky in that the above examples balance each other out, in that the first will swing up by .xxx1 and the other down by .xxx1, giving you .xxx3 in both, but there's no guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually not using the same values because the intermediate results are different:

```
double result1 = 2.1 + 1.2;
double result2 = 2.2 + 1.1;
```

Because doubles can't represent decimal values exactly you get different results.